# After changing a file in the Finder, Xcode was not able to locate the files on its own

Tags: ios, xcode, finder

I moved some files in the xcode project folder to a sub folder in the finder window for making my files in the project ordered.
After moving the files its not updated in the xcode. Instead, the files were shown in red color in the xcode project navigator. So I've to locate the each and every file in the finder and give the path everytime.
Is there any way to make the xcode locate the files which were copied or moved in its finder location ?

Answer (score 1):

Drag those files in groups and files of Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a folder to an Xcode project by dragging the folder from the Finder into your project. You'll see in the Project Navigator that the folder shows up in blue, and in the File Inspector, that the folder is listed as "Absolute Path" rather than "Relative to Group." When you modify this folder in the Finder, it will be updated in Xcode.